# Is there a word that means 'boring to death'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English that is more or less synonymous with 'boring to death', as for example, fratricide is synonymous with killing a brother?

I would guess that there probably isn't a  'proper' word for boring to death, but I'd be grateful for any intelligent suggestions!

Comment: This expression is a hyperbole (i.e. you can't really bore someone so much that they die) so there's no formal synonym, especially of the kind you suggest involving "-cide".

Comment: Can someone die of boredom in a hospital.

Comment: Certainly - this form of medical misadventure would be termed "death by iatrogenic stultification."

Answer (score 2):

***Stultify*** is very close.  [Stultify at Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stultify)

> When something stultifies you, it drains you of your energy,
>   enthusiasm, or pleasure. A well-acted Shakespeare play can be a
>   thrill. A poorly acted one can stultify like nothing else.
>
> The verb stultify is sometimes used in place of "bore" or "exhaust,"
>   but only if something is so boring or exhausting that it makes you
>   feel as though you might just die.